mremap with MREMAP_NOMOVE always return MFAIL with errno 12
I encountered a problem that mremap always outputs errno 12, regardless of the supplied sizes
#define CALL_MREMAP_NOMOVE  0
size_t size = ...;
void *p = mmap((void *)(0), size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
// example: p = 0x7f07d5d5d000
...
size_t new_size = size * 2;
p = mremap(p, size, new_size, CALL_MREMAP_NOMOVE);
// always p = (void *)(-1) regardless of the size value

This happens on systems with 64-bit addressing, I just can’t figure out what the problem is. I would be very grateful for your help.
The addresses returned by mmap are correct.
The only case where mremap does not return MFAIL is size = new_size

CALL_MREMAP_NOMOVE is not one of the constants mremap accepts. The default is to not move, and you pass MREMAP_MAYMOVE to indicate it's allowed to move... This also isn't a [MCVE]. The ... could include any number of things that change behavior.

What OS is this, and where is CALL_MREMAP_NOMOVE documented?  It's not a documented option for Linux or BSD, as far as I can tell, and Google doesn't seem to have ever heard of it.

@ShadowRanger #define CALL_MREMAP_NOMOVE 0.
about ...  in this example it says that regardless of the value substituted in ... the behavior remains identical

@mandesero: The idea of a [mcve] is that you fill in the ... with whatever it is that actually reproduces the bug for you, and provide a complete program that compiles, runs, and reproduces the problem.

Think about this from the point of view of someone like me who wants to help.  I'd like to see if I can reproduce the same behavior.  But I'd have to take your code snippet, choose values to fill in for the ..., write a main function, add some error checking code, include all the relevant headers.  It's very tedious and so I probably won't bother.  But if you do that part of it and provide complete runnable code, then someone like me will be more motivated to test the code and help you out.
